# I am struggling in this dataweave language

Tags: mule, dataweave

Input :

```
{
"payload": {
"Field_X": "X",
"Field_Y": 10,
"Field_Z": "Z",
"Field_W" : {
"sub_1": "value_1",
"sub_2": true,
"sub_3": "value_3"
}
},
"mapper": {
"A": "<payload.Field_X>",
"B": "<payload.Field_Y>",
"C": "Fields or text not mapped to payload",
"D": {
"subD_1": "<payload.Field_W.sub_2>",
"subD_2": "<payload.Field_W.sub_4>"
}
}
}
```

Output

```
{
"A": "X",
"B": 10,
"C": "Fields or text not mapped to payload",
"D": {
"subD_1": true,
"subD_2": null
}
}
```

Note: Pls note that hardcoding is not allowed as per the client's request.
Every key-value pair has to be looped.

Comment: Please explain how the output should be obtained from the input. This use case is not simple enough to understand just from the samples provided. Are the "mapper" elements literal or a kind of pseudo code? Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question. Also make the subject line related to the actual problem since it is completely generic and not useful.

Comment: This is the same question as asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834357/dataweave-transformation/73835886#73835886

Comment: @surendra  Please try to give meaningful titles to the questions so others can find it too

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the original question, the following DataWeave script should accomplish the goal.  I broke out the work into multiple functions so that it would be easier to follow.

```
%dw 2.4
output application/json

fun isExpression(value: String): Boolean = ((value startsWith("<")) and (value endsWith(">")))

fun extractExpression(value: String): Any = do {
  if (isExpression(value))
    dw::core::Strings::unwrap(value, "")
  else value
}

fun evaluatePath(context: Object, expression: String): Any = do {
  var tokens = expression splitBy "."
  ---
  tokens reduce (val, acc = context) -> acc[val]
}

fun retrieveMappedValue(context: Object, value: String): Any = do {
  var retValue = if (isExpression(value))
      evaluatePath(context, extractExpression(value))
    else value
  ---
  retValue
}

fun remap(context: Object, object: Any, fn): Any = do {
  if (object is Object) 
    entriesOf(object) reduce (val, acc = {}) -> dw::core::Objects::mergeWith(acc, {
      (val.key): remap(context, val.value, fn) 
    })
  else fn(context, object)
}
---
remap(payload, payload.mapper, retrieveMappedValue)
```